# Object Debugger Returns 503 error

Tags: facebook, webserver

I'm getting a lot of 503 errors out of the object debugger on a site I'm working on:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoganonymous.com%2Fthe-traveling-yogi-how-to-stay-cool-as-a-cucumber-across-time-zones%2F

I'm also missing thumbnail images when using the share button on posts (about 50% of the time I use it), which I believe is related. A sample post:

http://www.yoganonymous.com/featured-teacher/dan-wilf/

All the correct open graph meta tags are there. I'm at a point where I'm pretty much out of ideas as to how to fix this. Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

missing meta tag `<meta property="og:image" content="SRC HERE" />`

read this https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/214401762018741

Comment: Thanks for updating that link. So this is just an open bug at this point it looks like?